p-table: find out position of vertical scroll-bar
I have an PrimeNG p-table in an Angular app.
<p-table #tab [value]="logs" [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand" [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}"
[columns]="colssel" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines" [scrollable]="true" [scrollHeight]="getHeight ()"
(onFilter)="setColFilter ($event)" [loading]="loading">
....

I also have the columns with a filter.
I need to find out if its vertical scroll bar is on top or not.
How can I do that?

You could use the default javascript domElement.scrollTop key. 
This would give you a value between 0 and n to show its distance to the relative top of the element. 
So first access your desired element and then check for scrollTop. How you access the element and when is up to you. 
Example:
    const element = document.getElementById('table');
    const scrollTop = element?.scrollTop;
    const isPositionTop = scrollTop === 0 ? true : false;

As I already said, its up to you how to implement that. Access the element via ViewChild or document. selectors. Call the logic with a click or another trigger. 
The important part is: .scrollTop === 0 means your at the top of the element.
